# How can I reuse a subquery inside a select expression?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In my database I have two tables `Organizations` and `OrganizationMembers`, with a 1:N relationship.

I want to express a query that returns each organization with the first and last name of the *first organization owner*.

My current select expression works, but it's neither efficient nor does it look right to me, since every subquery gets defined multiple times.

```
await dbContext.Organizations
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Select(x =>
    {
        return new OrganizationListItem
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            OwnerFirstName = (x.Members.OrderBy(member => member.CreatedAt).First(member => member.Role == RoleType.Owner)).FirstName,
            OwnerLastName = (x.Members.OrderBy(member => member.CreatedAt).First(member => member.Role == RoleType.Owner)).LastName,
            OwnerEmailAddress = (x.Members.OrderBy(member => member.CreatedAt).First(member => member.Role == RoleType.Owner)).EmailAddress
        };
    })
    .ToArrayAsync();
```

Is it somehow possible to summarize or reuse the subqueries, so I don't need to define them multiple times?

Note that I've already tried storing the subquery result in a variable. This doesn't work, because it requires converting the expression into a statement body, which results in a compiler error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The subquery can be reused by introducing intermediate projection (`Select`), which is the equivalent of `let` operator in the query syntax.

For instance:

```
dbContext.Organizations.AsNoTracking()
    // intermediate projection
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Organization = x,
        Owner = x.Members
            .Where(member => member.Role == RoleType.Owner)
            .OrderBy(member => member.CreatedAt)
            .FirstOrDefault()
    })
    // final projection
    .Select(x => new OrganizationListItem
    {
        Id = x.Organization.Id,
        Name = x.Organization.Name,
        OwnerFirstName = Owner.FirstName,
        OwnerLastName = Owner.LastName,
        OwnerEmailAddress = Owner.EmailAddress
    })
```

Note that in pre EF Core 3.0 you have to use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First` if you want to avoid client evaluation.

Also this does not make the generated SQL query better/faster - it still contains separate inline subquery for each property included in the final select. Hence will improve readability, but not the efficiency.

That's why it's usually better to project nested object into unflattened DTO property, i.e. instead of `OwnerFirstName`, `OwnerLastName`, `OwnerEmailAddress` have a class with properties `FirstName`, `LastName`, `EmailAddress` and property let say `Owner` of that type in `OrganizationListItem` (similar to entity with reference navigation property). This way you will be able to use something like

```
dbContext.Organizations.AsNoTracking()
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Id = x.Organization.Id,
        Name = x.Organization.Name,
        Owner = x.Members
            .Where(member => member.Role == RoleType.Owner)
            .OrderBy(member => member.CreatedAt)
            .Select(member => new OwnerInfo // the new class
             {
                 FirstName = member.FirstName,
                 LastName = member.LastName,
                 EmailAddress = member.EmailAddress
             })
            .FirstOrDefault()
    })
```

Unfortunately in pre 3.0 versions EF Core will generate N + 1 SQL queries for this LINQ query, but in 3.0+ it will generate a single and quite efficient SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

How about doing this like

```
await dbContext.Organizations
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Select(x => new OrganizationListItem
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            OwnerFirstName = x.Members.FirstOrDefault(member => member.Role == RoleType.Owner).FirstName,
            OwnerLastName = x.Members.FirstOrDefault(member => member.Role == RoleType.Owner)).LastName,
            OwnerEmailAddress = x.Members.FirstOrDefault(member => member.Role == RoleType.Owner)).EmailAddress
        })
    .ToArrayAsync();
```

Comment: The part that the OP didn't want to repeat `x.Members.FirstOrDefault(member => member.Role == RoleType.Owner)` is still repeated in your code, so what problem does your code solve?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
await dbContext.Organizations
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Select(x =>
    {
        var firstMember = x.Members.OrderBy(member => member.CreatedAt).First(member => member.Role == RoleType.Owner);
        return new OrganizationListItem
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            OwnerFirstName = firstMember.FirstName,
            OwnerLastName = firstMember.LastName,
            OwnerEmailAddress = firstMember.EmailAddress
        };
    })
    .ToArrayAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried that. This is not possible and will result in an error: `A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree.`

Comment: Have u tried using 'AsEnumerable()' to this linq? Not suggesting that directly as it will bring query result in memory and that might have unwanted effects to rest of the code.